# Unable to bootstrap terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Relatively new to terraform. I am able to spin up servers but I am struggling with the bootstrapping. I have been trying variations of my shell script in user_data but nothing seems to work:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile =                 var.profile
  region =                  var.aws_region
}

resource "aws_instance" "Test_1" {
  ami = var.amis_ubuntu_18_04
  instance_type = var.instance_type_t2_micro
  subnet_id = var.public_subnets
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  security_groups = ["*****************"]
  
  user_data=<<EOF
  #!/bin/bash 
  sudo mkdir /var/test1
  EOF
  
  key_name = var.Keypair


  tags = {
    Name = "Test 1"
    Environment = var.environment_tag
    Owner = "Me"
    project = "Test 1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **indentation is incorrect** in the `user_data`. If you want to keep it you need to use `-EOF`, not `EOF`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "Test_1" {
  ami = var.amis_ubuntu_18_04
  instance_type = var.instance_type_t2_micro
  subnet_id = var.public_subnets
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  security_groups = ["*****************"]
  
  user_data=<<-EOF
  #!/bin/bash 
  sudo mkdir /var/test1
  EOF
  
  key_name = var.Keypair


  tags = {
    Name = "Test 1"
    Environment = var.environment_tag
    Owner = "Me"
    project = "Test 1"
  }
}
```